# Shared memory usage is piling up

Tags: shared-memory

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with kernel 5.4.0-70-generic. Shared memory keeps piling up until system hangs as it doesn't have any memory left.

I'm using Prometheus + Grafana to monitor my system resources and from their graph it's visible that it takes approximately 4-7 days since restart until shared memory reached 20 GB. But it doesn't stop there, it keeps growing until I make another restart.
[image: Screenshot from Grafana]

Same amount of shared memory usage can be seen from `free -h` command.
[image: Screenshot of free -h]

The usage of tmpfs seems to be low:
[image: Screenshot of df -h | grep tmpfs]

Shared memory keeps growing even if I close all the apps and not using the computer. What could be the cause of such behavior? How could I start investigating the problem? How could I find out which processes use that much shared memory?

```
$ ipcs -m --human

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      size       nattch     status      
0x00000000 3145729    martsraits 600          256M     2          dest         
0x00000000 2588677    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1245191    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 5832713    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 10         martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1212427    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 12         martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1212429    martsraits 600           64M     2          dest         
0x00000000 32785      martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 2064402    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 5537814    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1114138    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 8945695    martsraits 600         23,3K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1507360    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 2916388    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 4816933    martsraits 606          8,2M     2          dest         
0x00000000 4816934    martsraits 606          8,2M     2          dest         
0x00000000 4816935    martsraits 600          128M     2          dest         
0x00000000 3670057    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 3309611    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 1441844    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 2555960    martsraits 600            8M     2          dest         
0x00000000 917564     martsraits 600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 3899453    martsraits 600          512K     2          dest
```

The sum of size column in `ipcs -m` is only 500M.

Comment: looks like something's leaking a lot of shared memory. find out what it is and fix it (or replace it if it can't be fixed).  you can find out what's using shmem with `ipcs -m`

Comment: I update my post, added `ipcs -m` output. What conclusions can I make from this? To me it seems that it doesn't show what is using most of the shared memory as the sum of `ipcs -m` is only 500M but shared memory usage is more than 20G.

Comment: There's nothing obvious there, maybe try running it as root (otherwise you only get shmem from processes owned by your uid).   Once you've found a shmid that's using a lot of memory, you can use `ipcs -p` match it to a process id (e.g. if the shmid is 2555960, run `ipcs -p | awk '$1 == 2555960'`).

Comment: I get exactly the same result when running `sudo ipcs -m`.

Comment: Does 'ls /dev/shm/\*' give any useful information?

Comment: I second @C.M. request since ipcs will report only about SYSV shared memory. When your problematic segments are most probably of the POSIX kind.

Comment: Can you share the output of df -h | grep tmpfs ?

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/how-can-i-find-a-memory-leak-of-a-running-process

Comment: Thanks to everyone for trying to help. The problem disappeared without me doing anything special. So I don't know what caused it and don't know what made it go away. It could have been some software update which fixed it but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this just now on an embedded system, and my issue was `tmpfs` - specifically, logs are stored in there (I need to change that), and they took up too much ram. And yes, in the output of `free` it showed up as taking up shared memory.

Comment: That's what I get for skimming the question... just now noticed you looked in `tmpfs`. Eh, leaving this answer for future people who also skim the question.